# Pandas dataframe - Performance of get_value in apply

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with about 1M lines, and 3 columns (`sentence`, a string in the 100-char range, `lang`, a 3-char string, and `i_sent`, an int).

I'm trying to generate a new series using a function called `compute_coverage`, which takes in a sentences and its corresponding language, and returns a float:

```
absolute_coverage = df.apply(lambda x: compute_coverage(x['sentence'], x['lang']),
                             axis=1)
```

`compute_coverage` is a fairly simple function, but generating the series takes a long time (about 50s). After profiling (results below), it turns out that a large marjority of the time is spent in pandas' `get_value` function, presumably to get `x['sentence']` and `x['lang']`.

Am I doing this horribly wrong? Is this expected? Is there a better way to perform an row-wise operation?

Thanks!

---

Edit:

I guess what I'm coming at is is there a way to avoid calling `get_value()`? For instance, if I do

```
x = df.apply({'sentence': lambda x: compute_coverage(x, 'fra')})
```

(which obviously returns incorrect results, but performs the same amount of computation), run time drops by 90%.

Function body:

```
def compute_coverage(sentence, lang):
    words = sentence.split()
    return len(set(words)) / (lang_vocab[lang] * len(words))
```

and `lang_vocab` is an 8-element dictionary.

---

```
         120108317 function calls (114648864 primitive calls) in 150.379 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time
   List reduced from 141 to 10 due to restriction <10>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
  2729722   13.090    0.000   83.294    0.000 base.py:2454(get_value)
        1   11.105   11.105  150.064  150.064 {pandas._libs.lib.reduce}
  1364861   10.287    0.000   16.268    0.000 <ipython-input-16-0ab58d43622d>:3(compute_coverage)
  2729722    8.953    0.000   95.187    0.000 series.py:598(__getitem__)
  2729722    7.476    0.000    7.476    0.000 {method 'get_value' of 'pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine' objects}
  8189190    7.460    0.000   16.088    0.000 {built-in method builtins.getattr}
13648677/8189224    6.484    0.000    9.794    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
  5459444    6.244    0.000   20.539    0.000 {pandas._libs.lib.values_from_object}
  1364864    5.801    0.000   17.845    0.000 series.py:284(_set_axis)
  8189277    5.637    0.000    8.747    0.000 {built-in method builtins.isinstance}
```

Comment: 1 million function calls is bound to take a while, even if you do consider it constant time for one function call... Also , can you post the function body?

Comment: I've edited my post to add it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is extracting (get_value) 2 times with one value each

```
df.apply(lambda x: compute_coverage(x['sentence'], x['lang']),
                         axis=1)
```

can be rewritten  as

```
df[['sentence', 'lang']].apply(lambda x: compute_coverage(*x))
```

It is be faster as both values are selected in one attempt (this is further unpacked and passed as parameters to `compute_coverage` function).

With 100,000 rows data frame this first approach took 7.77s, and for the same data second approach took 4.78s. **The second approach seems to be 40% faster**.

---

For my data frame with 100,000 records

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('abcd')*100000, 
                   'b':list(range(4))*100000, 
                   'c': list(range(3,7))*100000
                  })
def f(x, y):
    return str(x)+str(y)
```

`df.apply(lambda x: f(x['a'], x['b']), axis=1)` took 7.66 s
`df[['a', 'b']].apply(lambda x: f(*x), axis=1)` took 4.67 s
`df.apply(lambda x: f(*x[['a', 'b']]), axis=1)` took 1min 54s

running time measured using `%%timeit`  in jupyter notebook (python3)

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, and it sounds like a good idea, but on my own test it performs very similarly to the original: `%time x = df[['sentence', 'lang']].apply(lambda x: compute_coverage(*x), axis=1)` gives me 56s, vs 53s for the original. I don't know where the difference comes from.

Answer (score 1):

After looking around, it looks like

```
x = pd.Series(map(lambda x: compute_coverage(x[0], x[1]),
                  zip(df.sentence, df.lang)))
```

takes 9s, 7 of which are spent inside `compute_coverage`, so it looks like it can't get *much* better without optimizing that function.

It's probably not the best way to do it, but it works well enough in the meanwhile.

Comment: Using `apply` function runs the function in parallel using underlying C/fortran libraries, and further optimizations may happen under hood. Using inbuilt `map` function is pure python generator function. It is strange how this `map` is faster than `apply`